# Issue with setting environment variables permanently in linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I want to set up a global environment variable **permanently** into the shell, so i do not set it every time i open another shell or another log-in session.

I have set the variable using `export` as following:

```
$ export pass='my_pass'
```

However when i use another active shell to restore this variable using `echo` as following:

```
$ echo $pass
```

The variable does not exist, so it only exist in the local shell of setup.

I have tried putting it into the `.bash_profile` but this also did not work.

Comment: This sounds like the Python process which needs the variable is not a child of the one which does the `export`, but we really have no way to guess without seeing the actual code.

Comment: That much is clear, but how you are setting the variable or why you expect it to be visible in another process is not.

Comment: Your description sounds *vaguely* like you are doing `os.environ['var'] = 'value'` in Python, and then attempting to access `$var` in a process which is not a child of that Python process; but then you are also talking about `.bash_profile` and `export` which s not a Python command. I really can't guess what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Again, `export` only affects children of the shell in which you issue this command.

Comment: Or conversely, if you launch Conda from a menu which is not a child of your login shell, figure out how to set and export the variable in that environment. If you are using a Linux GUI, the desktop manager's settings are probably where you want to look (and/or maybe your `.profile`; but remember you can't use Bash syntax there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/.bash_profile` is only sourced on login (i.e. after you've typed your username & password) -  `~/.bashrc` is sourced for interactive non-login shells.

So I'd add the variables into `~/.bashrc` (don't forget to `source` it first if you're running the python script afterwards from the same shell). This way, when you open a new shell, bashrc will be sourced and your environment variables will be available.

Edit:
As others have said in comments .. running an export command in one shell, won't make that variable availble in another shell - you need to add it to your `~/.bashrc` to make it avaiable in other shells